# Why does auto port speed negotiation not work on SFP fiber uplinks?

Tags: networking, switch, fiber

I have two switches (Switch 1 and Switch 2) that are different models, but are from the same manufacturer. They have SFP ports where on Switch 1 the interface type is 1000X while on Switch 2 the SFP port interface type is 10GX. When both ports are set to "Auto" they cannot establish a connection. I have to manually set both ports to 1000/Full. Should they be behaving like this, or is this an issue with the software?

NOTE: I also tried the same thing on two different, but same model switches, and got the same result.

Comment: The optics and encoding are different for the SFPs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Autonegotiation only applies to twisted pair copper, not fiber.

Fiber SFPs each only support a single link type, over a single optical fiber type. You have to make sure you have the same technology of fiber SFPs at both ends, and you have to use the right kind of fiber (and make sure it doesn't exceed the distance limits for that link type).

Your switches might have autonegotiation settings for those SFP ports just in case you use SFPs for twisted pair copper, but that setting is probably meaningless in the fiber case.